# How to deploy handlebars(hbs) , Nodejs, mongoDB application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, deployment, hbs

I create a project using hbs, Nodejs, mongoDB ,so I need to deploy it on internet. Can someone tell how to host it using Netlify or railway app, vercel etc. free services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log in on railway using your Github account. When you finish setting that up. The following you can do is create a new project on railway based on the repo of the project on Github you want to deploy.

Documentation: https://docs.railway.app/

Comment: it can host using hbs and add database as mongodb

Comment: @DedeHolsing yes, for all the information on this you can check their documentation.